# Oracle hint failure

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

When I run the PL/SQL block after the CREATE statement, I receive the duplicate key error I would expect if I did not add the hint.  Any ideas to why the hint does not work?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Sandbox.Clue
(
    ID number,
    Clue_Name varchar2(8 BYTE),
    Quantity number,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

DECLARE
    i number := 1;
BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. 10
    loop
        INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Sandbox.Clue.ID)*/ INTO Sandbox.Clue
        (
            ID, Clue_Name, Quantity
        )
        VALUES
        (
            mod(i, 2), 'Tip', 44
        );
    end loop;
END;
```

Comment: What does `select * from v$version` give you? That hint was introduced in 11.2. Before that version it's not available.

Comment: I am, indeed, using version 11.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint you specified was almost correct. In the hint you should specify the correct index_name, or the column list. Given the fact that the index_name is system generated, I would specify the column list.

```
DECLARE
    i number := 1;
BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. 10
    loop
        INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Clue(ID))*/ INTO Clue
        (
            ID, Clue_Name, Quantity
        )
        VALUES
        (
            mod(i, 3), 'Tip', 44
        );
    end loop;
END;
/
```

also see [Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG)

Comment: Interesting, the hint appears to work only when the table name is NOT qualified by the schema name.  I assume you noticed the same, as you omitted schema name completely from the code.

Comment: INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Clue(ID))*/ INTO Sandbox.Clue

Comment: @user10478 The syntax for the table(column) part of the hint looks similar to that used for the index hint, for which the documentation states to specify the table name without schema name, or the alias if one is used. I'm not sure whether aliases are accepted for single table inserts (the docs suggest that they are) but it would be interesting to see whether the hint needs the alias to be used if one is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax will need either:

table_name,index_name  or
table_name(column_name)

in the hint, not just the column name as you have in your example.

Comment: @dezso it shows the syntax explicitly. anony_mouse: I've removed the comment about the link as ypercube has edited in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In APEX, where a user can actually log into a particular schema (thus qualifying table names is optional), the follow code works while logged into Sandbox...

```
DECLARE
    i number := 1;
BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. 10
    loop
        INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Clue(ID))*/ INTO Sandbox.Clue
        (
            ID, Clue_Name, Quantity
        )
        VALUES
        (
            mod(i, 3), 'Tip', 44
        );
    end loop;
END;
```

...however, the following code does not work in the same environment...

```
DECLARE
    i number := 1;
BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. 10
    loop
        INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Sandbox.Clue(ID))*/ INTO Sandbox.Clue
        (
            ID, Clue_Name, Quantity
        )
        VALUES
        (
            mod(i, 3), 'Tip', 44
        );
    end loop;
END;
```

...while the single qualification is the only difference.  I also attempted Sandbox(Clue(ID)) inside the hint, which was equally unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of BUG#11865420 and BUG#17397545 as duplicates still might be inserted when using the IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX-hint.

I would rather *NOT* use the hint until the issue on BUG#17397545 has been fixed (and confirmed).

Comment: Could you add some links to help readers with these bug reports?